# tensorflow keras conv1d : ValueError: len(dilation_rate)=1 but should be -1

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I try to build a custom Keras regularize with tensorflow as backend.
Executing the following piece of code gives me an exception :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras    
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(10,))
x  = keras.backend.conv1d(inputs, tf.constant([-1,1]), padding = 'same', dilation_rate=None)


 x  = keras.backend.conv1d(inputs, tf.constant([-1,1]), padding = 'same', dilation_rate=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/arthur/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3775, in conv1d
    data_format=tf_data_format)
  File "/home/arthur/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 779, in convolution
    data_format=data_format)
  File "/home/arthur/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 842, in __init__
    num_spatial_dims, strides, dilation_rate)
  File "/home/arthur/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 625, in _get_strides_and_dilation_rate
    (len(dilation_rate), num_spatial_dims))
ValueError: len(dilation_rate)=1 but should be -1
```

i can't understand what i am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `tf.constant([-1,1])`. This is a place for kernel which should have dimension like `input_length,in_channel,out_channel`.